# How to change font for structured text editors in STS 3.7.2?

Tags: fonts

How to change font for structured text editors in STS 3.7.2 ? I try to change font in Preferences/General/Appearance/Color and Fonts/Structured text editors. But it doesn't work.

Comment: welcome! however, please note that Stackoverflow is *not* for general hardware and software questions but specifically for programming problems. This question should be asked over on https://superuser.com instead

Comment: "specifically for programming problems" - I had in mind that changing the font for structured text does work....

Comment: this is a general software question, not a question related to source code that doesn't work.